# Hide form_for if condition equals true Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement

I was wondering if there was a method in ruby that i could use to hide a form_for if a condition is true, so for example

```
<% if current_user %>
```

then i would like to hide my form

I know that i can display:none with css or jquery but if i could do it within the if statement then that would be great

Comment: What’s wrong with wrapping your `form_for` in the `if` statement you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can type in your view file:

`<% unless current_user %>`

```
  <%= form_for .... do %>
   .
   .
   .
  <% end %>
```

`<% end %>`

this way, the form will be rendered only if `current_user` is false or nil

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, will make a note of the unless statement